# Run-time error '424' "object required" when trying to copy sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I get this error on the line indicated below. What am I doing wrong?

> Run-time error '424'
>   object required

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\vinod\Desktop\dt kte\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
Sheets("Payout Summary").Select
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' <~~~~ Error occurs here
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It will help someone to answer your question if you can give us more information - in what way is it not working? Does it give an error?

Comment: Run time error '424' object required......here is the error "Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)"

Comment: You appear to be trying to copy worksheet "Payout Summary" from every workbook in folder "C:\Users\vinod\Desktop\dt kte\" to the workbook containing this macro. Am I correct? The result will be worksheets "Payout Summary", "Payout Summary (1)", "Payout Summary (2)" and so on with no indication of the source of each worksheet. I can post some better code if my guess is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because `Sheet` is <strike>Nothing</strike> Empty. You haven't declared any variable `Sheet`; when you use it for the first time, it defaults to a Variant whose value is Empty.

Change the faulty line to:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

Though really, you should read this: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

And also use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules to force yourself to declare all variables explicitly. Had you done that, you would have been able to find your error much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

a small improvement on Jean-François Corbett's answer:

replace the lines

```
Sheets("Payout Summary").Select
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

with

```
Sheets("Payout Summary").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

You do not need to "Select"!!! You, apparently recorded a Macro and are kind of duplicating it.
Macros are there to just to look at and improve upon :)